# Angular - is element child of other

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to find a pure Angular way of determining if a clicked element is a child of another. In jQuery I would do has() but not sure which way to do it in Angular besides running through all the children and doing a compare.

jQuery:

```
if($(someelement).has(another)) { };
```

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I'm recoding the Bootstrap clickover (fancy popover) plugin. I need to determine if the body was clicked on but check that its not the popover itself that was clicked. Trying to do a click anywhere and close feature. In the code above 'someelement' is the element popover div - 'another' is the is the return from the body click function - https://github.com/lecar-red/bootstrapx-clickover/blob/master/js/bootstrapx-clickover.js#L76  - I have no issues detecting body clicks but the has() line has me stumped.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add a click handler to the `$document`? This is how the dropdown toggle works - [check out the code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdownToggle/dropdownToggle.js) - and it should be super simple (like two or three lines of code) to add this to the popover plugin.

Comment: are you supporting ie < 9?

Comment: You could use the methods provided by AngularJs built-in jqLite http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element "jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM"

Comment: I'll take a look at the dropdown - I was mostly translating it line by line so I'll take a look at that approach. @Fresheyeball - IE <9 would be nice yes

Comment: I know about those - but they are very limited - and has() doesn't exist

Comment: The dropdown toggle suffers from same issue. It will close if you click anywhere on it. I'm trying to prevent just that.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed in a different way. I'll leave the question as is as I would still like to know the most efficient way to do has() in Angular

Comment: Can you please share your solution

Answer (score 0):

You could go the other way around.

Instead of asking whether B is a child of A, you can ask whether A is an ancestor of B:

```
function isAncestor(ancestor, element) {
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    while (parent && parent!=ancestor) {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    return parent==ancestor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put this here, as i'm trying to solve the same problem and thought it might be useful to someone else, even though it's not a strict replacement for `has()`.

My first solution was to use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`.

If you're dealing with a rectangular target you can check the x and y of the click event against the bounding rect of `element` (which is an angular.element)

```
$document.bind('click', function(evt) {
    var x = evt.x,
        y = evt.y,
        rect = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    if(x > rect.left && x < rect.right && y > rect.top && y < rect.bottom) {
        //you've clicked somewhere in the element
    }
});
```

IE8+ works fine, but there's a minor bug in 5-7

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Annoyingly if your element contains other elements that don't affect it's width/height that won't work. But you could use this (slightly hacky) solution

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var clicked = false;

        element.on('click', eClickHandler);
        $document.on('click', clickHandler);

        function eClickHandler(event) {
            clicked = true;
            $timeout(function() {
                clicked = false;
            });
        }

        function clickHandler(event) {
            if(!clicked) {
                // click occurred outside
            }
        }
    }
```